# Scan for wireless devices

Tags: networking, 16.04, wireless, router, tools

I am looking for a way to search for WIFI devices (such as phones, other computer etc) using either a regular computer running Ubuntu or similar, or a router running openWrt. I am not looking for ways to list wireless devices connected to a network, since that can be easily done with wireshark or using `nmap`, and `nmcli dev wifi` can be used to list all visible wireless networks.

I am more looking for a tool like `hcitool` that can be used to list BLE devices with the command `sudo hcitool lescan`

Maybe a tool as `hcitool` does not exist to list wifi devices for ubunut but it seems like it could be done in openWrt since it runs on routers.

In short I am looking for a way to list (all 'visible') WiFi devices, that are not necessarily connected to the same network as my device is.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `wavemon`. This tool should give you at least a basic overview.

Comment: It is indeed a very neat program and think it could be useful in the future, but it is not quite what I am looking for. I am more interested to see/discover other wireless devices, like a phone or other computer.

Comment: What is it exactly that you want? WiFi and BLE devices only? Other devices?

Comment: I am looking for a way to see WiFi devices, that are not necessarily connected to the network my device is connected to

Comment: You could also have a look at [Kismet](https://www.kismetwireless.net/)

Comment: Kismet looks promising, might even be able to use it with a hackrf